# D3 version 5, how to chain promise to chart build

Tags: javascript, d3.js, promise, visualization

I want to chain JS promise to D3 v5 chart building, and want to resolve it after the animation, but it's not working, the code below also show different types of attempts in the comments, none of them is working, option 3 cause exception (*Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined*), option 2 and option 1 just fail silently. Please advise, thanks heaps! PS: dataset *TrumpStatsFiltered* is correct, as I tested the code without the promise.

```
var dur = 400;
var t = d3.transition().duration(dur);

var durR = 400;
var tR = d3.transition().duration(durR).ease(d3.easeBounce).delay(220);

var swingState1 = d3.select('#svgSwingStateGraph1');

var swingState1Promise = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        swingState1
            .selectAll('text')
            .data([TrumpStatsFiltered], d => d.swing_state_1)
            .join(
                enter => {
                    enter
                    .append('text')
                    .attr('x', -150)
                    .attr('y', 30)
                    .text(d => d.swing_state_1 == 'Trump' ? "Trump":"Hillary")
                    .attr("stroke", d => d.swing_state_1 == 'Trump' ? "green":"orange")
                    .transition(t)
                    .attr('x', 75)
                    //.on("end", response => resolve(response)) //- option 2
                },

                update => {
                    update
                    .transition(t)
                    .text(d => d.swing_state_1 == 'Trump' ? "Trump":"Hillary")
                    .attr("stroke", d => d.swing_state_1 == 'Trump' ? "green":"orange")
                    //.on("end", response => resolve(response)) //- option 2
                },

                exit => {
                    exit
                    .transition(tR)
                    .attr("stroke", "tomato")
                    .attr('x', 200)
                    .remove()
                    //.on("end", response => resolve(response)) //- option 2
                }
            )//.on("end", response => resolve(response)) //- option 3

        swingState1.on("end", response => resolve(response)) // option 1
    })
}

Promise.all([swingState1Promise()]).then(() => {

    ***I need to hit this point!***
});
```

Comment: I'm not surprised you are struggling. d3's documentation is pretty close to impenetrable.

Comment: @Roamer-1888, yes, and I found D3 is significantly lack of community support as well. Probably not many people are really using it as it doesn't add too much practical value to the organisation.

Comment: As far as I can make out, start/update/exit are three phases of an animation. If each of the chains takes `.on()` without error (your option 2 attempt), then it seems reasonable that there should be an "end" event. However, the Promise can only be resolved once, therefore it seems appropriate to chain `.on("end", resolve)` only to the `exit` phase.  You will need also to chain `.then(...)` to the function call eg `swingState1Promise().then(() => console.log("resolved"));`, in order to find out if the end event ever fired.

Comment: On that last point, `Promise.all()` is not necessary.

Comment: Seems odd that your option 3 should throw while option 1 doesn't. Seems to indicate that the .join()` method returns something other than `swingState1`. In which case, what does it return and might it be useful?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`transition.end()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#transition_end) which

> Returns a promise that resolves when every selected element finishes transitioning.

Because you have three selections—namely, the enter, update, and exit selections in `.join()`—you can create an array to collect those promises and pass it on to `Promise.all()` to await resolution of those promises when all corresponding transitions have come to an end. The following code shows how this could be done for the enter selection; obviously, the same pattern can be applied to collect promises from the update and the exit selection as well.

```
const transitions = [];                // Collect promises for enter, update, exit transitions.

someSelection.data(someData)
  .join(
    enter => enter.append("whatever")
      .attr("", "")                    // Modify some attributes.
      .call(enter => transitions.push( // Push the returned promise to the collector array.
        enter.transition()             // Create a new transition.
          .attr("", "")                // Attributes to be transitioned.
          .end()                       // Get the promise.
      ))
  );  

Promise.all(transitions)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Done");               // This logs when all transitions have finished.
  });
```

Have a look at the following snippet for a working demo:

```js
const svg = d3.select('body')
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 600)
    .attr("height", 200);

const transitions = [];

svg.selectAll(null)
  .data([500, 1500, 1000])
  .join(
    enter => enter.append('circle')
      .attr('cx', (_, i) => i * 50 + 100)
      .attr('cy', 100)
      .attr("r", 20)
      .attr("fill", "red")
      .call(enter => transitions.push(
        enter.transition()
          .duration(d => d)
          .attr('fill', "blue")
          .end()
      ))
  );  

Promise.all(transitions)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Done");
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.15.0/d3.js"></script>
```