# d3.js chaining multiple transitions using selection.join

Tags: join, d3.js, merge, transition

I’m doing some refactoring from the General Update Pattern to the new(er) Data Joins. I have some async transition chaining needs, so my code looks like this so far:

```
const transitions = [];

svg
  .selectAll('g')
  .data(someData)
  .join(
    (enter) => {
      const gEnter = enter.append('g');
      gEnter.append('rect'); // I also have multiple adjacent elements I need to append
      return gEnter;
    },
    (update) => {
      const t1 = update
        .transition()
        .attr(...);
      const t2 = update
        .select('rect')
        .transition()
        .attr(...);
      transitions.push(t1.end(), t2.end());

      return t1; // ??? I know I need a materialized selection here, but which one?
    }
  );

return Promise.all(transitions);
```

This code works! The trouble is, I’d like **update transitions to be merged with enter**. In this example, the update transitions do not run on enter. Any ideas on how I can accomplish that?

Work so far inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60470507/4017364)